# Adding an item to array does not re-render polymer template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to render a dynamic list of items using a template of `dom-repeat` like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items={{numbers}} as="anumber" >
  <div>
    {{anumber}}
    <paper-button class="deleteThisNumber" index={{index}}></paper-button>
  </div>
</template>
<paper-button id="addNumber"></paper-button>
```

Each item has a button which will delete this item.

There is also a button **outside** of the `dom-repeat` template that tries to add an entry to array `numbers`. The JS looks like this:

```
Polymer ({

is: "something",

properties: {
    numbers: {
        type: Array,
        value: ["1"]
    }
},
removeByIndex: function (array, index) {
    return array.filter(function (elem, _index) {
        return index != _index;
    });
},
attached: function () {
    var myself = this;
    $(this).on('click', '.deleteThisNumber', {}, function (e) {
        myself.numbers = myself.removeByIndex(myself.numbers, this.index)
    });
    this.$.addNumber.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        myself.numbers.push("123");
    })
},
...
});
```

**The result is:** deleting works, but adding does not.

By saying "works", I mean the list reflects the change by adding/removing an entry in the `DOM`. I checked the property `numbers` it is correctly modified all the time. So why does Polymer not reflect changes of an array property to a template if the change is addition(array.push)? How should I fix this? (I am open to any suggestions other than manually adding divs.)

My Polymer version is 1.X

Answer (score 3):

Change the code for array push to :

```
    this.$.addNumber.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      myself.push("numbers", "123");
    })
```

There has to be an **observable change** in order to render the updated property or subproperty. An **observable change** is a data change that `Polymer` can associate with a path.

If you manipulate an array using the native methods (like `Array.prototype.push`), you must notify Polymer after the fact. OR, use the Polymer methods for array mutations.

> When modifying arrays, a set of array mutation methods are provided on
>   Polymer element prototypes which mimic `Array.prototype` methods, with
>   the exception that they take a `path` string as the first argument. The
>   `path` argument identifies an array on the element to mutate, with the
>   following arguments matching those of the native `Array` methods.
>
> These methods perform the mutation action on the array, and then
>   notify other elements that may be bound to the same array of the
>   changes. You must use these methods when mutating an array to ensure
>   that any elements watching the array (via observers, computed
>   properties, or data bindings) are kept in sync.
>
> Every Polymer element has the following array mutation methods
>   available:
>
> ```
> push(path, item1, [..., itemN]) 
> pop(path) 
> unshift(path, item1, [...,
> itemN])
> shift(path)
> splice(path, index, removeCount, [item1, ..., itemN])
> ```

[Learn More](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data)

Comment: This works great! Can you explain a little bit about why I can call a push function to a Polymer dom?

Comment: Here's why, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I discover one issue on both this approach and the solution I found below: If I delete a few items and add a few more, especially when I delete items in the middle of the array, than data binding problem happens: data of a few entries in the array get bound together. Have you run into similar problem?

Comment: If you change the delete to use myself.splice to perform an in place removal of the item without creating a new array, you should not have any problems.  No need for notifyPath if you do that.

Comment: Great! `myself.splice` works. However `myself.push` still causes data in multiple entries get bind together. So to speak I am going to use `myself.splice` for deleting and my answer below for addition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution is to force a notifyPath with a little more:

```
myself.numbers.push("123"); //before only has this
myself.notifyPath('numbers', myself.numbers.slice()); //added
```

Referred to [https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2068#issuecomment-120767748](http://github%20issue%20discussion)

Answer from @miyconst

Answer (score 0):

More than one way you can fix your code.

1) The way you've already been using when you delete an item.

```
this.$.addNumber.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    myself.numbers.push("123");
    myself.numbers = myself.numbers.slice();
})
```

2) Answer from yourself (with slight changes)

```
this.$.addNumber.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    myself.numbers.push("123");
    myself.notifyPath("numbers");
})
```

3) Answer from @Ofisora

```
this.$.addNumber.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    myself.push("numbers", "123");
})
```

Here's why the fixes work, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes